# Formula for filtering all duplicate data pairs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm making a [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kWt6Q5TGvoxhXdj8FxT9PlGejSw7Z5e8PaLSIziTlNI/edit#gid=0) to check duplicate data.
Where data that wants to be duplicated is in the "Sampel1" column and the duplicate checking results are in the "Status" column.

[image: Table1]

The formula that I have made is:

```
=if(COUNTIF($A$3:A3, A3)>1, "Duplicate", "No")
```

I want when table 1 is filtered only for duplicates, the results can be seen in the picture below:

[image: Table results that have been filtered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **paste this in B2:**

```
={"Status"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), 
  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3:A, ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A3:A,
  "select *", 0),
  "select count(Col1), Col1 where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Col1", 0), 
  "select Col2 where Col1 >1", 0)&"♥Duplicate", "♥")), 2, 0), "No"), ))}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: why when I fill in the number A column, the number that should not be the same but instead duplicates are detected?
https://ibb.co/X3srbPQ

Comment: @LutfiCreativesys check the fix in your spreadsheet