# How to pull data from one sheet to another based on duplicate values in a specific column. Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need to figure out how to pull rows based on non unique data in a column to another sheet.

For example in the below table I want to pull rows based on duplicates in column "Number" so in my other sheet I would end up with rows 1 and 3.

| Name | Color | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Danny | Purple | 4 |
| Grace | Yellow | 12 |
| Bob | Pink | 4 |
| Peter | Green | 10 |

This seems to be easy to do with a unique value but I have been really struggling to figure it out when I need non unique. Am I missing something simple is there a !=UNIQUE option or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

@user0 has the key to this in [Formula for filtering all duplicate data pairs in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124497/196152). This answer is an application of that solution.

---

Insert this formula in cell D1:

`={"Status"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C5),  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C5, ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(C2:C5, "select *", 0), "select count(Col1), Col1 where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Col1", 0),  "select Col2 where Col1 >1", 0)&"♥Duplicate", "♥")), 2, 0), "No"), ))}`

---

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

[image: snapshot]

---

**Extract "Duplicates"**

`=query({A1:D5},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col4 = 'Duplicate'")`

**Extract Non-Duplicates**

`=query({A1:D5},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col4 <> 'Duplicate'")`

Comment: I do not need to highlight if it is a duplicate I need to move the full row to a new sheet if it is a duplicate.  This is still useful though.

Comment: Think of Column D as a necessary evil (a “helper” Column) without which the other queries would not work. On a tangent, this formula does not “move” any data. It will make a copy of the duplicates, but the duplicates will remain in the original list. If you truly want to “move” the data, then you need a script. In any event, if the answer has been useful, perhaps you would consider accepting it.